# HTML Button won't calculate using onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like for someone to be able to enter their property value, click the button and it performs the calculations in the cells and returns a value for total taxes by adding all of the other cells. I took an excel sheet with calculations an turn in to HTML code.

I cannot get the calculations to appear nor an error. I have tried HTML buttons and forms with onclick events and fields with onchange events.

Here is the code I have used (most recently).

```js
function calculate2(){
var i=0; for (i=0;i<= 32;i++) {calculate();}} 
function calculate(){ 
Excel2Html.C5.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B5.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C6.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B6.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C7.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B7.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C8.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B8.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C9.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B9.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C10.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B10.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C11.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B11.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C12.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B12.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C13.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B13.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C14.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A2.value)*parseFloat(Excel2Html.B14.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C15.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.A5.value):parseFloat(Excel2Html.A14.value))*0.01)* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
Excel2Html.C16.value=(Math.round((SUM(parseFloat(Excel2Html.C5.value):parseFloat(Excel2Html.C15.value)))* 1E+21))/ 1E+21 ; 
}
```

```html
<form name="Excel2Html">
<table border="0" margin="0" padding="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr height="20"px; style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#0563C1; text-align: left; ">Find Property Value from <a href="http://www.town.duxbury.ma.us/Public_Documents/DuxburyMA_Assess/FY2016%20Assessed%20Value%20by%20Address.pdf"> HERE</a></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; " id="txtValue" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 46.3884px;" style="border:0px;" >


<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input type="text" name="A2" value="" size="8"
style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 46.3884px; width: 237.688px ; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; ">

 <form>
<input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Calculate Taxes" onclick="calculate2()" />
</form> 

<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 30.3924px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; </td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 60.7848px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: center; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; ">Tax Bill Allocated By Percentage</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; ">Tax Bill Allocated By Dollars</td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >

<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A5" value="General Government" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>



<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B5" value=".0406" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C5" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A6" value="Public Safety" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B6" value=".1058" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C6" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A7" value="Education" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B7" value=".4773" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C7" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A8" value="Public Works" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B8" value=".0587" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C8" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A9" value="Human Services" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B9" value=".0096" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C9" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A10" value="Library & Recreation" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B10" value=".0215" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C10" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A11" value="Shared Services (net of offsets)" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B11" value=".1553" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C11" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A12" value="Debt Service" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B12" value=".0105" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C12" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A13" value="Exempt Debt Service (net of offsets)" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B13" value=".1093" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C13" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="A14" value="Recurring Articles" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="B14" value=".0113" size="8" style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C14" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 45.5886px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; ">CPA Surcharge  1%</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: right; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C15" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 45.5886px; width: 237.688px; text-align: right; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
<tr height=" 49.5876px;" style="border:0px;" >
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; "></td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: 0px; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; ">Current FY 2016 Tax Bill =</td>
<td style="height:20px; width: 237.688px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top: solid 1px #000000; border-bottom: solid 1px #000000; border-right: solid 1px #000000; border-left: solid 1px #000000; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; text-align: left; "><input type="text" onchange="calculate2()" name="C16" value="" size="8"disabled="disabled"  style="background-color: transparent; border:0px; height: 49.5876px; width: 237.688px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family:Arial; color:#000000; "></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Is `SUM` defined? And what's the `:` in `parseFloat(Excel2Html.C5.value):parseFloat(Excel2Html.C15.value)` supposed to be? Also, have you looked at the console in the dev tools? Are there any errors there?

Comment: I am not sure about the SUM defined part, but the colon is supposed to be the equation for adding cells C5 to C15. Unfortunately what I found in the console was no help. I am too "green" at this.